# RunTIme Error 3622 How and where do I add dbseechanges

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have a global module that records a log of actions taken for each record. I have recently moved my back end to SQL server and the global module VBA code no longer creates a record. I can manually create a record  but sadly the VBA code below just shows up the runtime error 3622, "you must use the dbseechanges option with openrecordset when accessing a SQL server table that has an identity column."

Can anyone explain where to put the "dbseechanges" in the following code and why this is the case so I can replicate in future.

Thank you

```
Public Sub LogIt(description As String, Optional notes As String = "")
    

    Dim userID As Long
    Dim RecordID As Long
    Dim LeadProvider As Long
    
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As Recordset
    userID = Nz(Forms!mainmenuf!UserIDtxt)
    RecordID = Nz(Forms!recordviewertemplatef!RecordID)

    
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("logt", dbOpenDynaset)
    

    rs.AddNew
    rs!userID = userID
    rs!RecordID = RecordID
    rs!description = description
    If notes <> "" Then rs!notes = notes
    rs.Update
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have seen other people get answers to this problem, sadly trying to replicate this in a logical way hasn't worked. I'm hoping someone can simply tell me where I need to place "dbseechanges" for this to work.
I have looked at all related questions and can't get their fixes to work with my code...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22790969/ms-access-error-3622-vba.

Comment: does: db.OpenRecordset("logt", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges) work?

Comment: yes that's perfect, I tried just adding that before and it came back with the same error. Thank you so much for your help it was really stumping me.